# Can I get emplacement of `sources.list` in cmd on a Modified UNIX?

Tags: unix

i would like to know how can I get the path to `sources.list` on a modified UNIX which have `apt` and other base packages on it , like `gpg` and `sudo`. Does `apt` can identify the path to `sources.list` ?

He is using it , so he should be able to locate it, right ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way, but `apt-config dump` will show all of `apt`'s configuration variables.  On my system, the `Dir::Etc` variable gives the directory where the file is located, and `Dir::Etc::sourcelist` gives its name.

You can also read in the `apt-config` man page about the `shell` option which may be more useful for processing this data in a program.